# How can I count valid clicks for my ads?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to build my own advertisement system. I want the user to be able to get a specific amount, say 5 cents, from each click the ad gets.

But I am facing a problem. I don't want my users to click bomb the ads so the earn more. I want to count 1 click per user per ad.

This is what I have come up with so far ...

```
<?php

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_ip WHERE ip = '{$ip}'");

if(!isset($_COOKIE['ad_click'])){
    $_COOKIE['ad_click'] = 'Ad number';
}elseif(mysql_num_rows($query) < 1){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_ip (ip, time) VALUES ('{$ip}', " . time() . ")");
}else{
    // ad 1 more click to user account
}

?>
```

My main problem is that people can delete cookies and change their ip address. So this won't work in the real world.

Comment: well IP does not eqaul user, so that will never work

Answer (score 1):

There's no perfect way to identify a user, but there are enough imperfect ways that, if you use them all you can make a pretty good guess.

- **IP address** should probably be the first thing to check. The IP would generally stay the same during a single session and that would weed out any layman trying to clickbomb.
- **User Agent** will tell you the browser and OS

On the client side there's actually a lot you can do. Check out [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/):

- Standard HTTP Cookies
- HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) Pinning
- Local Shared Objects (Flash Cookies)
- Silverlight Isolated Storage
- Storing cookies in RGB values of auto-generated, force-cached 
  PNGs using HTML5 Canvas tag to read pixels (cookies) back out
- Storing cookies in Web History
- Storing cookies in HTTP ETags
- Storing cookies in Web cache
- window.name caching
- Internet Explorer userData storage
- HTML5 Session Storage
- HTML5 Local Storage
- HTML5 Global Storage
- HTML5 Database Storage via SQLite
- HTML5 IndexedDB
- Java JNLP PersistenceService
- Java CVE-2013-0422 exploit (applet sandbox escaping)

Pay attention to unusual click frequency and look for strange patterns.

Comment: Can you explain in terms of code please, thanks

Comment: I didnt even get a upvote no im not gonna write free code for you

Answer (score -1):

Bearing in mind that:

1. cookie can be cleared
2. ip can also change during connection
3. one ip might also be shared by more than one user
4. browser(user-agent) will not change frequently, however a user might have multiple browsers per computer

If you are not a super famous site, you can treat one ip per user per day.

You can take into account: browser (user-agent) value, as well as browser plugin info.